# How do i fix Win7 app compatibility shim with DISABLEUSERCALLBACKEXCEPTION

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, registry

I have a very large C# .NET4 WinForms application that has been in production for over 18 months.  We are finally testing it on Windows 7 (this large corp. has not migrated yet).  The app starts up fine and runs until we start a very large process (multiple fetches from the DB and many forms and controls are bound).

The very first time we start that process on Win7, something crashes and Win7 creates a app compatibility shim around our `*.vshost.exe`.  When I look in the registry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers
```

it shows the `vshost.exe` with a value of `DISABLEUSERCALLBACKEXCEPTION`.

I did a search and came up with very little.

Does anyone know what type of code would cause this?  I would like to fix the code to prevent the shim.

Comment: The crash caused it.  Don't fix the shim, fix the crash.

Comment: That is what I asked, what type of code would cause my app to crash (where it didn't crash in XP) to where Win7 would need create the shim?

Comment: Buggy code, of course.  Or anything that disregards UAC restrictions.  If you never ran this on Vista or Win7 then that's pretty likely.  Get everybody a new dev machine, about time.  And a VS update if they are still stuck at 2005 or less.  The manifest that VS2008 and up includes in the program should also avoid shims.

Comment: Searching around the net, it appears that this shim is added when your application crashes inside a wndproc.

Comment: Larry's right. The easiest way to prevent this is to mark yourself as Win7-compatible via a Manifest (read my answer below for the gory details)

Comment: It should be noted that the crash has nothing to do with "UAC restrictions". One might argue that masking those exceptions should have been required; in the same way masking floating point exceptions is now part of the calling convention in x64 programming  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235300.aspx)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read this blog post thoroughly, I've explained the whole thing:

http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/

### Short version

Exceptions that crossed the user-kernel-user boundary were lost on 64-bit Windows.

Starting with Windows 7, when a Native 64-bit application (i.e. not 32-bit on a 64-bit OS) crashes in this fashion, the Program Compatibility Assistant is notified. If the application doesn’t have a Windows 7 Manifest, they show a dialog telling you that PCA has applied an Application Compatibility shim.

That the next time you run your application, Windows will emulate the Server 2003 behavior and make the exception disappear.

In order to **keep** these exceptions (since you ***want*** them to happen), add a "I'm designed for Windows 7" manifest entry:

```xml
<assembly>
    <!-- We were designed and tested on Windows 7 -->
    <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
        <application>
            <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
            <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows Vista -->
            <!--It's important to keep this too, since Vista has no idea about
                        Win7's supportedOS GUID -->
            <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/
        </application>
    </compatibility>
</assembly>
```