# Default Application Compatibilty Manifest for new Visual-Studio projects?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm currently fighting with some [app compat settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [specifically a certain shim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600735/how-do-i-fix-win7-app-compatibility-shim-with-disableusercallbackexception), and looking into the [`compatibilty` section of the application manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Details aside, one thing that strikes me as odd is that, even with Visual Studio 2015, there doesn't *seem* to be any default for the application compatibility manifest(*) -- or rather, default is none, thereby defaulting to "Windows Vista" wrt. the stuff listed in [Application Manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This seems totally odd to me, but maybe I'm missing something:

Every new application in either Visual-C++/Native or C# that is *newly* created by any team that is not aware of this stuff (and I daresay there's a *lot* of such teams) will run in Windows Vista compatibility mode. Is this actually the case? Is there a rationale for this?

---

(*):

```
...
<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
  <application> 
    <supportedOS Id="{...}"/>
```

---

And while I'm at it: **[Good overview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/09/10/manifest-madness/)**

- List of [Windows 7 vs. Vista `compatibility` bullets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [For Windows 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848036.aspx)
- [For Windows 8.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn302074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [For Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, newly created projects (I only verified .NET projects, no native C++) in Visual Studio 2015 will have no `compatibility` section and will run under Windows Vista context, as you correctly said. It's easy to check. If you create new console (for example) project and go to project properties -> application, you will see that in manifest section the following is stated by default: "Embed manifest with default settings". What's that manifest with default settings? Build console project and look with any resource viewer and you'll find:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

As you see, no compatibility section. Then run that console project (put `Console.ReadKey()` for it to not exit immediatly). Open Resource Monitor (`resmon`), go to CPU section and add column "Operating System Context". You will see "Windows Vista" at that column for your fresh console application - so it's definetly runs under Windows Vista context.

As for rationale - I can only make assumptions about that, here is one. The goal of compatibility section is stated as:

> This section helps Windows determine the versions of Windows that an application was **designed** to target

When you create new project in Visual Studio it is not known if it was designed (which means - tested on) specific version of Windows with the knowledge of behavior changes introduced in later versions of Windows - so a safe approach was taken to default to behavior which is **the same** on all versions of Windows (starting with Vista) - as opposite to default to behavior which is **different** on different versions of Windows. With different behavior you (ideally) should test your application on all versions of Windows you support. When behavior is the same - you can test on any *one* version.

So it's reasonable to provide the same behavior for developers who are not aware of those behavior changes - their application tested on Windows version of their choice will happily run on other versions (regarding features related to compatibility section mentioned).

Comment: Cheers. Details and rationale appreciated. It's still all a bit muddy to me I've got to say, but I have to admit I've never used this in production.

Comment: @MartinBa well if you were on their side when millions of developers can write and run some unknown code on every version of windows - you would have been on a safe side always too :)